# Facebook Sharing won't use specified image & link

Tags: html, facebook, share

I'm using Facebooks' Open Graph protocol :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Here's code for a test page. My understanding is that when someone "likes" this, the image icon that placed in the post on their
page should be the one specified in og:image, and the linkable url in the post should be the one specified in og:url.

In reality, it seems to truncate the URL to the domain, and instead of using the image provided it picks one seemingly at random (my guess is it's just taking the first image it sees from a scan or specified elsewhere in the code).

Am I doing anything obviously wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Site Title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.org/videos/index/16922653" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/104/367/104367616_200.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site" />
    <meta property="og:app_id" content="5555555555" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/104/367/104367616_200.jpg" />

</head>

<body>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.mysite.org/videos/index/16922653" show_faces="false" width="450" />
</body>   

</html>
```

Update: @echese

Good suggestion. Ran it, got this feedback from the "debug" section:

```
Data Source "website" extracted from <meta property="og:type" />
Data Source "My Site Title" extracted from <meta property="og:title" />
Data Source "http://www.mysite.org/videos/index/16922653" extracted from <meta property="og:url" />
Data Source Extracted 1 values from <meta property="og:image" />: http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/104/367/104367616_200.jpg
Data Source "My Site" extracted from <meta property="og:site_name" />
```

Looks like it understands the image url. It suggested some iframe code which I tried but still no dice, I don't get the image I specify.

Comment: The `website` type is typically meant for the root website, for example you'd use it on `http://example.com/`, you may have better luck with the `article` type. Also, Facebook caches the Open Graph data, so you'll also need to run it through the linter to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to see if you can find any errors on your pages.

Answer (score 0):

hmm maybe (maaaaaaybe) it's because you dont have the og namespace on the html tag..
or.. maybe because the image's url is on a different domain than your page?

good luck

Comment: maybe because the image's url is on a different domain than your page => I thought that too but I didn't see anything in their docs that listed such a restriction. Going to try echeese's suggestion of using a type other than "website". I keep feeling like there's some hidden documentation someplace I should be reading?? lol